# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected :, found {

Tags: graphql, apollo

Here are my graphql queries / mutations.

I'm getting the error:
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected :, found {

I don't know which one of them is wrong.

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const CategoriesQuery = gql`
    query categoriesQuery(
        $id: ID!,
        $country: String!,
        $name: String!
    ) {
        sections(
            id: $id,
            country: $country,
            name: $description
        ) {
            id,
            createdBy,
            createdDate,
            lastUpdate,
            name
        }
    }
`;

export const ItemsQuery = gql`
    query itemsQuery(
        $id: ID!,
        $category: String!,
        $url: String!,
        $alias: String!,
        $name: String!
    ) {
        items(
            input {
                id: $id,
                category: $category,
                url: $url,
                alias: $alias,
                name: $name
            }
        ) {
            id,
            createdBy,
            createdDate,
            lastUpdate,
            name,
            category,
            url,
            alias,
            description
        }
    }
`;

export const AddCategoryMutation = gql`
    mutation ($category: CategoryInput!) {
        addCategory(category: $category) {
            id
        }
    }
`;

export const AddItemMutation = gql`
    mutation ($item: ItemInput!) {
        addItem(item: $item){
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the second query. You need to change this

```
items(
  input {
      id: $id,
      category: $category,
      url: $url,
      alias: $alias,
      name: $name
  }
)
```

To this:

```
items(
  input: {
      id: $id,
      category: $category,
      url: $url,
      alias: $alias,
      name: $name
  }
)
```

Add a colon after `input`

Comment: where is that file? on which file ?

Comment: these code snippets are the same or am i blind?

Comment: There is a colon after `input` on the second line

Answer (score 0):

In my case I realized that I forgot to add type to function

false:

```
    type Mutation {
   ...

    createMentor(mentoremail: String, password: ID)
    }
```

true:

```
type Mutation {
...   

createMentor(mentoremail: String, password: ID): Mentor
}
```