# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found [

Tags: graphql

After trying to run a React app, I get the following error:

"GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found ["

The specific mutation the error references is:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default gql(`
mutation($name: String!, $address: String!, $phoneNumber: String!, 
$allegedOffenses: String!, $courtDates: [AWSDate]!) {
createClient(
  name: $name,
  address: $address,
  phoneNumber: $phoneNumber,
  allegedOffenses: $allegedOffenses,
  courtDates: $[AWSDate]
) {
id,
name,
address,
phoneNumber,
allegedOffenses,
courtDates,
comments {
  items {
    commentId
   }
  }
 }
}`);
```

I tried using the troubleshooting steps found at [GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected :, found {](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877455/graphqlerror-syntax-error-expected-found/51880294), but didn't have any luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo in the mutation for `courtDates` parameter..

```
createClient(
  name: $name,
  address: $address,
  phoneNumber: $phoneNumber,
  allegedOffenses: $allegedOffenses,
  courtDates: $[AWSDate]
)
```

should be:

```
createClient(
  name: $name,
  address: $address,
  phoneNumber: $phoneNumber,
  allegedOffenses: $allegedOffenses,
  courtDates: $courtDates
)
```